# FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');

Tags: flutter

Out of nowhere i started getting this new error after i restarted my VScode

```
Compiler message:
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7: Error: 'sethrow' isn't a type.
      sethrow FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
      ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:15: Error: Expected ';' after this.
      sethrow FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
Failed to build bundle.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

my pubspec.yaml looks like this

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/couplephone.png
    - assets/images/background.jpeg
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/avatar.png
```

trying to figure out but google is not helping as i cannot find much info on this.

Edit: I'm getting this error now on all my flutter projects

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @etzuk the problem is i'm not sure where it is happening, i tried all my other flutter projects, same issue,... created new flutter project... same issue

Comment: What do you have in `$key`?

Comment: @Sebastian nothing i'm using "Image.asset('assets/images/avatar.png)" which gives no errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re-installed flutter in my mac and everything's working fine again.